# Get last line height of the pdf page

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

Is there any way to get last line height of the page of the pdf document, using iTextSharp 4.6.1? I can't use iTextSharp 5 due to the legal issues.

Comment: You probably mean to say that you can't use iTextSharp 4.6.1 due to legal issues: http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/can-itext-217-or-earlier-be-used-commercially Please update your question in that sense.

Comment: Was there a 4.6.1 of iTextSharp at all?

Comment: That been said, if you want to do serious content analysis with iTextSharp, you should use a really current version, much had been improved in the context of parsing.